# Comparision theorem for distance function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Assume that $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are conformal metrics on the unit disk which is a geodesic disk of radius $1$ w.r.t. both metrics $\rho$ and $\rho'$, and assume that $\rho'$ has a constant Gauss curvature $K'$ which is greater than the curvature of $\rho$. Let $d$ and $d'$ be the corresponding distance functions defined on the unit disk. Which is the best reference for the inequality $d(0,a)\le d'(0,a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Bob Osserman's 1999 Notices articl](http://www.ams.org/notices/199908/fea-osserman.pdf)e (which is beautifully written, and copiously referenced).

Comment: I have seen that paper, but i guess that the result have been obtained before?

Comment: @misko Osserman has very extensive references, and under various hypotheses, there are versions of the results due to Ahlfors, Yau, and Troyanov (the last of which not long before Osserman's paper). So, whatever Osserman attributes to other people is due to them, and whatever he does not is due to him :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not correct. A bigger sphere has smaller curvature. Half of a sphere is a conformal disk.